# Wait for async function return in Python

Tags: python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio

I have this Flask route which can take a get and post request at the same time

```
@flask_class.route('/receive_files', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def receive_files():
    if request.method == 'POST':

        # do stuff
        return stuff

    if request.method == 'GET':
        # waits for post request to finish or time out
        #  
        time.sleep(3)  # work around 
  
        # return stuff from post request if condition met
```

I want the function to wait x time for the return value of the post request if a get request is incoming reading about [python asyncio module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html). I was thinking about using an asynchronous approach for this problem, but dont know how to implement it.

I got around it by using a global variable which gets changed inside the function while using time sleep inside the get request part to make sure that the global variable value changes in time, but this approach is highly error-prone.

Comment: What library are you using to do your requests inside of `receive_files`?

Comment: `https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.request`

Comment: No, that's not what I mean. Your comment reads *"wait for post request to return"*, to me that means you're doing a server-side HTTP request for something, in order to fulfill the client's `GET` request.

Comment: in the post request the function processes a file, some data from the file should be transmitted to the client  via a ajax call, im not using any extra librarys for that

Comment: Then I don't understand your code. You have two branches, `if request.method == 'POST'`, which does something and returns, and `request.method == 'GET'` which (currently) sleeps for 3 seconds. The two do different things and they don't run at the same time. What exactly does *"wait for post request to return"* in the GET branch mean? What POST request?

Comment: @Tomalak Maybe the OP wants to wait for a _previously_ issued POST request to return. I.e. store something in session marking that a POST is in progress, and then delay the subsequent GET until the POST has been cleared. That's just a guess.

Comment: @user4815162342 Probably, but it's not clear from the question. That the OP now has deleted the code comment without providing any additional explanation doesn't help, either.

Comment: @user4815162342 thats exactly what i want,  the get request should be put  on hold till post request is finished or x time is up, and then the get request should return the return value if the post rquest if a condition is met.

Comment: That's not a sensible approach. You want to do something (`POST /receive_files`) and this request should return immediately (I suppose?) and one millisecond later you issue a `GET /receive_files` *from the same client*, but this request should wait until the previous one (which already returned!) is done. With this approach, you could just as well spare the detour entirely and make the original `POST` request wait. If you want to asynchronous messaging with the client (i.e. status/progress reports), explore dedicated messaging channels like web sockets, or use regular polling via Ajax.